# Making specific UITableViewCells have a different background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my table view, I want to the first two items to have a light green background color. I researched this topic earlier, and am using the code provided in those said answers, but it's not working for me. This is the code I have:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:144 green:238 blue:144 alpha:1];
}

else if (indexPath.row == 1)
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:144 green:238 blue:144 alpha:1];
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I better this code to be more efficient and effective?

Comment: What happens to the background?  Is just white?  Can you set a break point and see if the method gets called and the line cell.backgroundColor is actually executed.  I think the best place to set the background color in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: is your contentView in the TableCell is transparent? if not, maybe it stays above the cell.

Comment: It was white until I fixed how I used the colorWithRed... by passing in float values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:144.0/255.0 green:238/255.0 blue:144/255.0 alpha:1];
```

the values for the components are defined as floats between 0.0 and 1.0

> ```
> + (UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red
>                     green:(CGFloat)green
>                      blue:(CGFloat)blue
>                     alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> red
>       The red component of the color object, specified as a value from
>   0.0 to 1.0.
>
> green
>     The green component of the color object, specified as a value
>   from 0.0 to 1.0.
>
> blue
>    The blue component of the color object, specified as a value
>   from 0.0 to 1.0. alpha     The opacity value of the color object,
>   specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Thank you so much, you have to forgive me since I am a bit new to this. I will further read upon the documentation :)

Comment: @FaisalSyed I'm not sure if my comment is relevant here, but I recall that table view may also reuse cells (on osx at least), so you probably need to clear the color (and other tuned properties) in additional else{} branch.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:144 green:238 blue:144 alpha:1]
```

to

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:144/255.0 green:238/255.0 blue:144/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

As the [UIColor API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:) show the parameter of `red/green/blue`should be specified as a value **from 0.0 to 1.0**.